# How to remove multiple headers row in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file which i load to a database table using python and use pandas for transformations.

The file has repetitive headers after every certain number of rows as shown

```
 ProductID   Title             Date      Volume SalesAmount
    123         Face wash    6-17-2019     7       35
    124         Cleanser     6-17-2019     6       40
    125         Hair Spray   6-17-2019     3       33
    ProductID   Title         Date       Volume SalesAmount
    126         Hair Gel     6-17-2019     5       20
    127         Shampoo      6-17-2019     4       24
    128         Nail Varnish 6-17-2019     0        0
    ProductID   Title         Date       Volume SalesAmount
    129         Nail Color   6-17-2019     9       18
    130         Moisturizer  6-17-2019     3       27
```

And im desired output is one single header at top

```
  ProductID   Title             Date      Volume SalesAmount
    123         Face wash    6-17-2019     7       35
    124         Cleanser     6-17-2019     6       40
    125         Hair Spray   6-17-2019     3       33
    126         Hair Gel     6-17-2019     5       20
    127         Shampoo      6-17-2019     4       24
    128         Nail Varnish 6-17-2019     0        0
    129         Nail Color   6-17-2019     9       18
    130         Moisturizer  6-17-2019     3       27
```

I'm able to achieve it by index, by excluding the rows in pandas dataframe, but i want to know how to achieve the same using string comparison/regex in pandas or any better way of doing it.

Comment: `df = df[df['ProductID'].ne('ProductID')]`?

Comment: Is the number of rows set?  Are you aware of it before hand?

Answer (score 4):

A little more systematic than the comment that takes into account all columns:

```
df[df.ne(df.columns).any(1)]
```

Output:

```
  ProductID         Title       Date Volume SalesAmount
0       123     Face wash  6-17-2019      7         35
1       124      Cleanser  6-17-2019      6         40
2       125    Hair Spray  6-17-2019      3         33
4       126      Hair Gel  6-17-2019      5         20
5       127       Shampoo  6-17-2019      4         24
6       128  Nail Varnish  6-17-2019      0          0
8       129    Nail Color  6-17-2019      9         18
9       130   Moisturizer  6-17-2019      3         27
```

Comment: how does this work, i'm new to python, so your explanation would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be dropping those rows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv')

df = df[df['ProductID'] != 'ProductID']
```